# omxplayer not loading a playlist file

Tags: pi, playlist, omxplayer

So i'm trying to make my raspberry pi play a bunch of video files on it's own.
I got omxplayer setup and working to actually play video to the screen the pi is connected to and not the remote terminal and also working with the usb sound card.
(the pi is connected to composite video not hdmi and I couldn't get audio ova gpio working and this is a pi zero w so no headphone jack, so yes it's an odd setup)
I also setup an sh script to play video files.
[image: sh script]
and so on..
However, when it's finished with one video file and changes to another, the pi will show the terminal for a second while it loads the next video and then will play that video. I would like it if it didn't have to keep loading new individual omxplayer commands like this.
a workaround hack would be to some how blank the display of the terminal so I just get a second of black screen and then the next video. But what I would really like to do is to just make a playlist file and play that.
I tried m3u, m3u8, xspf and even html but I got nothing.
[image: default playlists]
I saw a script that mentioned a .pls playlist so I tried to make one of those, that indeed did seem to load something but didn't play it?
[image: pls playlist]
I tried editing in an absolute file path and just the normal file name and got the same result.
[image: loaded but not playing idk]

Temp hacks would be some how blanking the terminal display on the pi its self
or using something like ffmpeg to just combined all my videos into one huge video file, but I think a playlist file is going to be better in the long run, just have to figure out what playlist format omxplayer is happy with.